# How do i know whether `rehash` happened after i insert into an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I understand the `unordered_` stl containers keep a number of buckets that vary in number depending on the number of elements in the container. When inserting, if breaking a certain limit, the container will rehash to use more buckets, so each bucket is less full and faster to search. And that invalidates the iterators.

This means I shouldn't keep iterators to an `unordered` container. Except I can, if I update them after a rehash. But I couldn't find a reliable way to check whether an `insert` (be it `emplace` or whatever) caused a rehash.

Should I monitor `bucket_count()`?

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) says `Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`. Is that garanteed? Would it be reliable to do the following?

```
bool will_rehash = (max_load_factor()*bucket_count()) > size()+1;
```

Comment: That sounds like an implementation detail that the standard would avoid making a requirement on. I'll look through the standard to see if it contains any such language.

Comment: max_load_factor() is only a hint. An implementation is allowed to set an upper limit for the buckets in an unordered_map. Monitoring bucket_count is the only way to see if an rehashing has happen..

Comment: I couldn't find any such guarantee (doesn't mean it doens't exist). Interesting question, but I don't think I'd personally want to rely on it in production code. Seems way too brittle (and even if you're technically right, I'd always worry that the standard library implementer wasn't as thorough in his/her reading of the standard).

Comment: I just read through *n4810 §22.5.4 Class template `unordered_map`* and I don't see any specific guarantee about when iterators are promised to be valid or invalid.

Comment: @CoryKramer That's sounds like a good answer!

Comment: @user786653, I agree it's brittle, which is why I'm asking whether anyone knows of a way to have a strong guarantee. Maybe i'll find a way to `reserve()` more than I need beforehand, so it never rehashes.

Comment: @CoryKramer, you surely mean after any type of insert.

Comment: @Gabriel Correct I should have elaborated, I meant after an `emplace` or `insert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that re-hashing (as the process where actually a hash function is engaged) takes place once hash-map is growing:

1. calculating a hash is (relatively) computationally expensive
2. see below my example I quickly compiled, where I crafted a custom hash functor, which keeps track of times it is called:

   - whenever bucket count increases, there's no indication that hash function was called => we can infer that re-bucketing takes place instead of re-hashing

That means, that one may watch over bucket count to infer whether iterator should be invalidated (predicated the invalidation happens at the moment of re-bucketing)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<string, string> str_map;

struct my_hash {
    void        reset(void) { calls_ = 0; }
    size_t      calls(void) { return calls_; }
    size_t      operator()(const string& key) const {
                 ++my_hash::calls_;
                 return hash_fn_(key);
                }
 private:
        str_map native_hash_fn_;
str_map::hasher hash_fn_{native_hash_fn_.hash_function()};
  static size_t calls_;
};

size_t my_hash::calls_ = 0;


int main ()
{
 typedef unordered_map<string, string, my_hash> myMapType;
 myMapType mymap(1, my_hash());
 myMapType::hasher hash = mymap.hash_function();

 cout << "mymap has " << mymap.bucket_count() << " buckets" << endl;

 mymap["abc1"] = "blah"; // add 3 values
 mymap["abc2"] = "blah"; // just to see the hash calls tracking
 mymap["abc3"] = "blah"; // is working
 cout << "hash calls: " << hash.calls() << endl;
 hash.reset();

 for(size_t i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
  mymap[to_string(i)] = "blah";
  cout << "buckets: " << mymap.bucket_count() << endl;
  cout << "hash calls: " << hash.calls() << endl;
  hash.reset();
 }

 cout << "mymap has " << mymap.bucket_count() << " buckets" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
mymap has 2 buckets
hash calls: 3
buckets: 5
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 11
hash calls: 1
buckets: 23
hash calls: 1
buckets: 23
hash calls: 1
buckets: 23
hash calls: 1
mymap has 23 buckets
```

Disclaimer: though, I strongly believe that it's not a good programming practice to refer iterators after the container has changed in size. Even if it might not cause some fatal / undefined behaviors, it might (and most likely will) cause *some* side effects onto the programming logic. In case with the hash-map, consider a situation with a `begin()` iterator: after a few insertions/emplacements it won't be a true `begin` anymore. Even if re-bucketing did not occur, some new entries might get installed in front of it (which might affect the programming logic).

Comment: "rehashing" is a misnomer then, but it's what cppreference calls it. Thanks for the test!